# Access to the database file is not allowed

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7, .net-3.5, windows-xp

I have an WinXP application (which works perfectly in WinXP) which I am trying to install on Win7.  The installation was fine, but when I double click the application to load it, I get a message saying:

```
Access to the database file is not allowed [file path goes here].
```

At the moment, I have the connection set as:

```
SqlCeConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|/db.sdf")
```

I have also tried:

```
SqlCeConnection("Data Source=*|DataDirectory|*db.sdf")
```

and

```
SqlCeConnection("Data Source=*|DataDirectory|*/db.sdf")
```

for which I got a different error message:

```
The file name is not valid
```

Why is this happening and how do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the |DataDirectory| variable will be expanded as follow:

- For applications placed in a directory on the user machine, this will
  be the app’s (.exe) folder.
- For apps running under ClickOnce, this will be a special data folder
  created by ClickOnce
- For Web apps, this will be the App_Data folder

In Windows7 the directory `C:\program files (x86)\yourexefolder` cannot be written.
If you install your database in a subfolder of your application or in the same folder you get this error.

You should install your database to the %APPDATA% directory

For example in C# you can set the DataDirectory path in this way

```
string myDataDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\yourAppDataFolder";

// Set |DataDirectory| value 
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory",myDataDir);
```